# Need help to convert a short Objective-C routine to Java

Tags: java, objective-c

I am not sure the equivalent of mutableData in Java. and the Java function to convert raw data into ASCII encoded string.

```
+ (NSString*) encode:(const uint8_t*) input length:(NSInteger) length {
NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Is this really the way the method is defined?  I don't see the `input` parameter being used anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSData`, and its mutable variant `NSMutableData` are just object-oriented wrappers for byte buffers.

In Java, this is usually just a `byte[]`.

The `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, if I understand it correctly, is just an encoding that converts an 8-bit UTF-8 string and encodes it in a 7-bit clean ASCII encoding.  (Which may be a lossy transformation).  The equivalent of this would be to supply `US-ASCII` as an encoding to the constructor for `String`. I think the constructor you want is `String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)`

<strike>The interesting thing about how your NSMutableData is being created is the length that they specify:  `((length + 2) / 3) * 4`  This suggests to me that `NSASCIIStringEncoding` might be doing a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding to do the 8-bit to 7-bit transformation.  If that's the case, then the transformation isn't lossy after all.  The equivalent in Java would be something like the Base64 utility in Apache Commons.</strike>

**Edit:** On second thought, and after some searching, I don't think that `NSASCIIStringEncoding` is doing any Base64 encoding, but that it may introduce escape codes for characters that are not 7-bit clean, and the above length is just their calculated worst case for the length that might be needed if every character needs to be escaped.  So I don't think you would need the apache commons library at all:  just a `byte[]` and the aforementioned String constructor.

Answer (score 3):

[java.lang.String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has a constructor that takes a byte array and a character encoding (you could use `US-ASCII`)